# Is there a package/font which define those kind of arrows

Tags: symbols, arrows, unicode

looking for this type of arrows I can't find a link, any help is welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

with lualatex or xelatex and any font that has the characters in the block starting U+2BB0

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\sus}{Segoe UI Symbol}

\begin{document}


{\sus ^^^^2bb0 ^^^^2bb1  ^^^^2bb2 ^^^^2bb3}
\end{document}
```

---

with a modern texlive you should have `albatross` installed which will show you the available fonts, I get:

```
$ albatross 0x2BB0
        __ __           __
.---.-.|  |  |--.---.-.|  |_.----.-----.-----.-----.
|  _  ||  |  _  |  _  ||   _|   _|  _  |__ --|__ --|
|___._||__|_____|___._||____|__| |_____|_____|_____|

                    Unicode code point [2BB0] mapping to ?
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
│ Font name                                                                   │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ NewComputerModernMath                                                       │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Noto Sans Symbols2                                                          │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Segoe UI Symbol                                                             │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Symbola                                                                     │ 
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ 
│ Unifont                                                                     │ 
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 14):

DIY!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\rightuparrowraw{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.08]
 \draw (1,1) -- (-.5,1) -- (0,.5) -- (-.5,0) -- 
  (.7,0) -- (2,1.3) -- 
  (2,1.7) -- (2.5,1.7) -- (1.5,2.5) -- (.5,1.7) -- (1,1.7) -- 
  (1,.3);
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand\rightuparrow{\kern1pt\rightuparrowraw\kern1pt}
\newcommand\upleftarrow{%
  \kern1pt\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\rightuparrowraw}\kern1pt}
\newcommand\rightdownarrow{%
  \kern1pt\rotatebox[origin=c]{-180}{\reflectbox{\rightuparrowraw}}\kern1pt}
\newcommand\downleftarrow{%
  \kern1pt\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\reflectbox{\rightuparrowraw}}\kern1pt}
\begin{document}
x\rightdownarrow\rightuparrow\downleftarrow\upleftarrow X
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it is too sharp, round the corners a tiny bit

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\rightuparrowraw{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.08,
  rounded corners = .2pt]
 \draw (1,1) -- (-.5,1) -- (0,.5) -- (-.5,0) -- 
  (.7,0) -- (2,1.3) -- 
  (2,1.7) -- (2.5,1.7) -- (1.5,2.5) -- (.5,1.7) -- (1,1.7) -- 
  (1,.3);
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand\rightuparrow{\kern1pt\rightuparrowraw\kern1pt}
\newcommand\upleftarrow{%
  \kern1pt\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\rightuparrowraw}\kern1pt}
\newcommand\rightdownarrow{%
  \kern1pt\rotatebox[origin=c]{-180}{\reflectbox{\rightuparrowraw}}\kern1pt}
\newcommand\downleftarrow{%
  \kern1pt\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\reflectbox{\rightuparrowraw}}\kern1pt}
\begin{document}
x\rightdownarrow\rightuparrow\downleftarrow\upleftarrow X
\end{document}
```

[image]